# ChartJS - line graph, position tooltip

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have the following graph with 3 datasets. Everything works fine except for one small bug. I want to tooltip to be placed only on the first dataset, as it currently is placed on the average position of all datasets.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

I know that ChartJS has the positioners function (the one below), but I can't figure out how to ignore the other 2 datasets so the tooltip is sticked only to the first line graph

```
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.top = function (elements, eventPosition) {
      const tooltip = this;
      return ;
 };
```

Comment: Usually it should stick to the dataset you hover. Don't know what's wrong here. Why does your first dataset not appear at your legend? Is you data structure unusual? Have your tried `options.tooltips.position = 'nearest'`?

Comment: I removed the first dataset using a filter, as it always needs to be on. Yes, if I'm using nearest then the tooltip will attach to the second dataset if the 2nd one is closer to the mouse

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. Tooltip always on first/top dataset. Currently I don't know an answer, but I'm sure it's possible. If I find a way I let you know...

Comment: Thanks man, I'm also sure there is a solution to that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define a custom position function for tooltips. like this,

```
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.custom = function(elements, eventPosition) {
var x = eventPosition.x;
var y = eventPosition.y;
var minDistance = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var i, len, nearestElement;
var top_element = elements[0];
for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    console.log(elements[i].tooltipPosition().y);
    if (elements[i].tooltipPosition().y < top_element.tooltipPosition().y) {
        top_element = elements[i];
    }
}
var tp = top_element.tooltipPosition();
x = tp.x;
y = tp.y;

return {
    x: x,
    y: y
};
```

};

Once done, you can specify it in tooltips.options.

More information :

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes

Hope it helps!